# Exists function in q/kdb

Tags: kdb

I need to write a function in q/kdb which takes a variable v and returns 1b if v is
defined and 0b if it is not:

```
$ a:2
$ doesExist`a
1b
$ doesExist`b
0b
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
q)doesExist:{x~key x}
q)a:2
q)doesExist`a
    1b
q)doesExist`b
    0b
```

Comment: This may or may not work, depending on the type of item referenced by x. For example, if `value x` is a keyed table, `key x` will return a table, not the symbol x.

Comment: Thank you! this is an extremely useful command also for checking whether a table exists!

Answer (score 7):

```
key`.
```

Will give you all the variables in the current namespace.

Similarly

```
key`.foo
```

Will give you all the variables in the `.foo` namespace.

By extension:

```
`a in key`.
```

Will give you the boolean you're after

Answer (score 6):

Based on MdSalih's answer and pamphlet's comment, perhaps we can test the opposite. Since key outputs an empty list if the variable is not defined, we should test for that, which gets us around the keyed table problem.

```
q)AnswerToLifeUniverseAndEverything:42
q)doesExist:{not () ~ key x}
q)doesExist[`AnswerToLifeUniverseAndEverything]
1b
q)doesExist[`UltimateQuestionToLifeUniverseAndEverything]
0b
```

Comment: Nice addition! This is very handy.

Comment: But not if its an empty dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Based on @compassionate_badger's answer and @Helios's comment, I suggest the following function:

```
doesExistsGlobal:{[sym]
    if[-11h<>type sym;'"The input is not a symbol"];
    exists:not ()~key sym;
    if[exists;:exists];
    / Either sym does not exist, or value of sym is ()!()
    $[0b~@[value;sym;0b];:0b;:1b];
 };
```